# How to create a "resume structure" based on shell functions return value

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, exit-code

Let say, i have 3 functions as below:

```
#!/bin/bash

f_1()
{
if [ -d "/home/xxx/yyy" ];
   then
       return 0
   else
      return 1
fi
}

f_2()
{
if [ -d "/home/xxx/yyy" ];
   then
       return 0
   else
      return 1
fi
}

f_3()
{
if [ -d "/home/xxx/yyy" ];
   then
       return 0
   else
      return 1
fi
}
```

I want to construct a way to do the below:

excute function 1 ....if return is 0 continue with ....excute function 2....and so one,  else (return 1) stop the loop.

Also i want to "resume", at the next execution starting with the function that failed.(returned 1 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a "stateful" application that remembers anything from the last run, you need somewhere to store the last state. The easiest solution is a filw, so we'll use that. The file will be called "next_command", but basically we can use any other file name as well.

Next, we need the "conditional or" statement. It takes the form of `a || b` and is evaluated lazily. This means: If the first command is successful, the entire statement of `a || b` is already true, so later statements are not executed anymore. We can use this to only execute the second command if the first failed - it's somewhat shorter than an "if ... ; then ... fi"-construct, though that would of course also work.

And last but not least we will use the case-construct to jump to the correct part of the code when we load a previously saved state.

The following code does what you request:

```
# ...
# your functions here
# ...

save_state() {
    echo "$1" > next_command
}

load_state() {
    cat next_command
}

# this means: save the output of load_state in the var state
# use f_1 as default)
state="$(load_state)"

# this means: take the content ofd $state, use "f_1" as default if it's empty
# and then, compare it's content to each pattern noted below. For the first that 
# matches, execute all code until you encounter ;;
case "${state:-f_1}" in 

    f_1)
        f_1 || {
            save_state f_1
            exit 1
        }
        ;& # this is a fall-through - it means we continue executing code in the following cases

    f_2)
        f_2 || {
            save_state f_2
            exit 1
        }
        ;&

    f_3)
        f_3 || {
            save_state f_3
            exit 1
        }
        ;; # here, we do not want to continue but instead go to the end of the case

    *) # default, if sate is something invalid
        echo "Invalid saved state, terminating execution"
        exit 2
esac

# we went through everything, clear last saved state
save_state ""
```

Comment: wow, it works like a charm. You cannot understand how grateful i am. Thank you !!

Comment: an edit I made yesterday apparently saved as a seperate answer (I don't know how I f'd that up). I migrated the edit to this answer. the substitution of `${$(load_state):-f_1}` did not work as expected (apparently bash does not support that particular kind of nesting) on my version of bash. The edited version will work.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
f_1 && f_2 && f_3
```

I don't understand the resume you mentioned. What is a 'next execution'? Do you want to somehow save state between script executions? or within the same script re-execute the 'behavior'?